# Quasar Framework Flex Classes

Tags: css, flexbox, vuejs2, quasar-framework

Using Quasar Framework 0.15, I don't see any effect on using Flex related classes. A simple component:

```
<template>
  <q-page class="flex">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 justify-center">
        <q-btn-group>
          <q-btn label="1" />
          <q-btn label="2" />
          <q-btn label="3" />
        </q-btn-group>
      </div>
    </div>

  </q-page>
</template>
```

When I inspect the components, the div with class 'row', for example', don't has the full width as expected, no either any other Flex related classes like 'justify-start' or 'col-sm-6' seems to work.

My btn-group in this case is showing in top-left corner of the screen, as if no css was been aplied to it ('justify-center' should center it)

I'm running on web/material theme in a fresh install.

Answer (score 1):

you can use simple q-page without any class it will take full width. you can also use the fixed center class for centering content.

```
<template>
  <q-page>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 fixed-center">
        <q-btn-group>
          <q-btn label="1" />
          <q-btn label="2" />
          <q-btn label="3" />
        </q-btn-group>
      </div>
    </div>

  </q-page>
</template>
```